# Java backend + Angular 2 (or higher) frontend

Tags: angular, rest, jakarta-ee

I've been studying which is the best approach to deploy an production application using these technologies.

I heard some people saying that I should separate my server app from my client app but Why? Cause it seams to me that I'm only getting more servers/apps to handle. Is there a strong reason for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an architecture decision. There is no simple right or wrong here. There are pro and cons for both designs.

If you separate frontend and backend you have a clearer separation of concerns. You could let some people work only for the backend or only for the frontend side. You could define a build and deploy pipeline for frontend purpose and one for the backend side. Which is easier to understand and maintain as a mixed one. In such an approach you should define a clear api between frontend and backend. So, that both projects can be build separately as long as the api definition does not change. You could build tests against this api and mock services to launch the one side without the other (for development). For a microservice landscape, the separated design would normally be a better match.

Otherwise a combined approach is faster to implement. Each developer has the full overview of both sides and could easily start the whole application. You don't need a solution to integrate frontend and backend.